# Ambiguous if and else branches: Is the behaviour defined?

Tags: c++, c

I recently came accross some C++ code like the following:

```
if(test_1)
    if(test_2)
    {
         // Do stuff
    }
    else
       exit(0);
```

This is ambiguous, since the compiler could see this as:

```
if(test_1)
{
    if(test_2)
    {
    }
    else
    {
    }
}
```

or as:

```
if(test_1)
{
    if(test_2)
    {
    }
}
else
{
}
```

Is the behaviour of this code defined according to any standard (C, C++)? I saw this code in a C++ program on VC++, which seems to prefered the first solution.

Comment: That is not *ambiguous* as the standard determines how it has to be parsed, it might *look* ambiguous to you, but it is not to the compiler or other programmers that know how it is parsed.

Comment: You might want to read this: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dangling_else and this: http://drdobbs.com/blogs/cpp/231602010.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> Is the behaviour of this code defined according to any standard (C, C++)?

Yes, it is defined. In C (and all similar languages as I know), the "dangling else" binds to the last free if, therefore this interpretation

```
if(test_1)
{
    if(test_2)
    {
    }
    else
    {
    }
}
```

is correct.

Comment: +1 But as a note (to the OP), many consider good writing style to ALWAYS ALWAYS ALWAYS put braces for this (and other) reasons. Not for the compiler ambiguity (non-existant) but for human ambiguity and stupidity.

Answer (score 5):

There is no ambiguity. The `else` clause always refers to the closest `if` it can be attached to. From the [C++ standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2005/n1905.pdf) (6.4   Selection statements):

> In clause 6, the term substatement refers to the contained statement or statements that appear in the syntax notation. The substatement in a selection-statement (each substatement, in the else form of the if statement) implicitly defines a local scope (3.3).
>
> If the substatement in a selection-statement is a single statement and not a compound-statement, it is as if it was rewritten to be a compound-statement containing the original substatement. [ Example:
>
> ```
>    if (x) int i;
> ```
>
> can be equivalently rewritten as
>
> ```
>      if (x) { 
>            int i;
>      }
> ```

It ensues that the code you wrote can be rewritten as:

```
if(test_1)
{
    if(test_2)
    {
        // Do stuff
    }
    else
    {
        exit(0);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It is well defined. `else` is always paired with the nearest available `if`.

Answer (score 0):

It is Defined in C. An `else` always gets paired with nearest `if`;
therefore you should use proper braces to avoid ambiguity.

Answer (score 0):

Yes its not ambiguous, as the rules state where it is applied, but my GCC C++ compiler still gives a warning stating it is :

/brainModule/BrainModule.cpp: In function ‘void failExpiredPendingAndRunning()’:
../brainModule/BrainModule.cpp:158:16: **warning: suggest explicit braces to avoid ambiguous ‘else’ [-Wparentheses]**
             if (job->isExpired() == false)

g++ (Raspbian 6.3.0-18+rpi1+deb9u1) 6.3.0 20170516